# Scanning multi-language projects with SonarQube

Tags: javascript, c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to implement SonarQube (SonarCloud) to our development pipeline. We are using TFS (on-premise) and our project has just one repository. In this repository, we have two different applications, one .NET application, and one javascript application.

The folder structure is like this:

```
|
|- NetProjectFolder
|- JSProjectFolder
```

And our build definition (which is working with Pull Requests) steps are like this:

1. SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis (for .NET project)
2. Visual Studio Build (build .NET project solution)
3. Visual Studio Test (tests of the .NET solution)
4. SonarQube Scanner CLI (To scan JS project)
5. SonarQuber Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis

I was thinking that step 4 and step 5 will analyze our .NET and JS projects and at the end, I will see a full report of our all projects. But, when step 4 completed it's automatically uploading the report of JS project and when step 5 completed it's overwriting JS report, uploading the report of .NET project.

In the end, there are only .NET project's report/warning / technical debt etc. Because step 5 overwriting step 4's result.

How can I configure these steps so SOnarQube can analyze both our JS and .NET projects properly?

Comment: We have lots of MVC/WEBAPI products with .cs and .js code on the same repo and AFAIK you only need a single scanner end step. All code will be evaluated. Never had to have a separate one per platform type and we get all code properly analysed.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your comment. So you mean, only properly configured "SonarQube Scanner CLI" is enough? Or you mean only step 1 and step 5 is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing, the behavior you are seeing is "by design", even though it is not very intuitive. In other words, you cannot chain Scanner for MSBuild and Scanner CLI.

Scanner for MSBuild is able to scan JavaScript code (and all other languages too) only if it is referenced from a project in the currently analyzed solution. For example, if your WebApplication project contains JS (or TS, Java, COBOL, etc.) files they will be analyzed.

When the non-.NET language files are not referenced in the currently analyzed solution, it is better to create a separate SonarQube project to store the analysis results from Scanner CLI.

We are aware of this limitation and we are planning to fix it in the near future, but right now I cannot commit to a specific date.

Comment: Hi Valeri, thanks for answer. As JS project developer of the project, I don't know if JS project is directly included to .NET solution (.sln file). NET project is developed by different team. So now I'm just using "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" step only (step 4 removed) and added "JSProjectFolder" to Scanner.Analysis.xml files "inclusions" part. It looks like it's now scanning JS projects, too.

Comment: @Eray as far as I know, `inclusions` filters the files that are specified by the `sonar.sources` property. If you are able to analyze files through the `inclusions` property, the .NET project either already has references to those files, or you set the `sonar.sources` property manually. Doing the latter could bring some weird behavior when analyzing with Scanner for MSBuild, because it also sets that property. I would advise not setting `sonar.sources` when using Scanner for MSBuild.

Comment: "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild" step is not uploading analysis results to SonarQube. Do you have any idea, why?

Comment: @Eray there could be many reasons, I strongly suggest opening a new thread (not to pollute this one with different questions and potentially help other people too) and add as much information as possible: errors, logs, etc. The first step would be to add `/D:sonar.verbose=true` parameter to the begin step of Scanner for MSBuild, then you could upload the logs here: https://www.dropbox.com/request/CszJAO1ZNXFVl1gwo5hA I'll try to reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Valeri, because of our customer policies it's not possible to share full logs. But I've shared the end of the analysis. Probably it will be enough. I've ran the scanner in verbose mode and I can see that it's scanning my all ".cs" and ".js" files as I expected. It's just not sending it to SonarCloud. I can not see anything in "Background Tasks" screen.

Comment: My configuration file is in root of the folder. `sonar.sources="."` and `sonar.inclusions="NetProjectFolder/**/*.cs,JSProjectFolder/**/*.js"`

Comment: Forget to mentions, the build request triggered by a PR.